# How to filter and object based on fields values using a filter with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm using Angular and I've this object:

```
$scope.items = {
    'abcdhx3': {name:'file1.jpg', type:'.jpg', size:30000},
    'sxcdhb2': {name:'file2.jpg', type:'.png', size:30000},
    'k4cdhx5': {name:'file3.jpg', type:'.jpg', size:30000},
    '23cdhd3': {name:'file4.jpg', type:'.png', size:30000},
    'ascdhx3': {name:'file45.jpg', type:'.png', size:30000}
};
```

I want to filter this object based on "name" and "type" values that I can get from input texts. So how can I do that using a filter in ng-repeat, for example: I want to show files that contains "file4" with type ".png".

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">
    <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem using a transformation filter like this:

```
angular.module('test').filter('itemsFilter', [
    function() {
        return function(items) {
            var list = [];
            for (var i in items) {
                list.push(items[i]);
            }
            return list;
        };
    }
]);
```

And filtering items before apply the search filter

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" />
Type: <input type="text" ng-model="search.type" />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | itemsFilter | filter:search">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    <li>{{item.type}}</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a simple [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

**HTML**

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" />
Type: <input type="text" ng-model="search.type" />
Whatever: <input type="text" ng-model="search.$" />
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    <li>{{item.type}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It doesn't works, I've tried that way without success, when "items" is an array it works, but "items" is an object and all filter properties are inside each item value.

Comment: @Ragnar You cannot filter an object. You would need to convert it to an array. Object is a mere kvp. You would need to implement your own filter for that

Comment: I'm trying using a filter function but it doesn't works "ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterFunction" with filterFunction(item, index) {..}